# Show me a simple example of how a COM object works for LibreOffice

Tags: python, debian, libreoffice, libreoffice-calc

I have Debian 11 and LibreOffice installed on my computer. I need to create a file for LibreOfficeCalc with one sheet and the number "42" in cell B2. This must be done using the LibreOffice COM object, this is important. Please tell me how I can do this using Python.

Comment: COM is windows feature, using that probably would require that you are running LibreOffice & python on top of WINE.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I'm seriously confused...

Comment: LibreOffice uses the UNO component model (analogous to COM) https://api.libreoffice.org/

Comment: This can be done in a number of different ways. First, research potential solutions online. You may find different types of approaches: 1) standard python-uno, either run from within LibreOffice, or listening on a socket, or calling soffice to specify a macro to run, 2) various wrapper libraries that call python-uno, 3) libraries that create .ods files without using LibreOffice. If you run into problems, edit the question to explain what you tried, including example code and any error messages encountered.